# pytest config within pytest.ini not being registered when pytest.ini is in tests subdirectory rather than project root directory

Tags: python, pytest

*pytest* is issuing a warning due to an unknown custom mark when running my test suite despite (hopefully) registering it correctly as per the *pytest* documentation (see https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/mark.html#registering-marks).

My Python project's structure is (simplified for the sake of this query):

```
my_project/
    src/
    tests/
        integration/
        unit/
        conftest.py
        pytest.ini
```

My `pytest.ini` is (again, simplified):

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
markers =
    incremental: marks related sequential tests to xfail after an earlier failure
```

because my `conftest.py` contains the `@pytest.mark.incremental` recipe outlined in the *pytest* documentation (see https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#incremental-testing-test-steps).

When I run *pytest* from the command line from within the root directory of my project (i.e. `/my_project/ $ pytest`), *pytest* issues the following warning:

```
PytestUnknownMarkWarning: Unknown pytest.mark.incremental - is this a typo?  You can register custom marks to avoid this warning - for details, see https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/mark.html
    @pytest.mark.incremental

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
```

However, if I tell *pytest* to run the tests directory (i.e. `/my_project/ $ pytest tests`) I get no such warning. Similarly if I move my `pytest.ini` file from within the tests directory back to the project root directory then again I don't get the error.

Is there a way to configure *pytest* so that I can keep my structure as `tests/pytest.ini` to avoid over-cluttering the project root directory, while still ensuring that my `pytest.ini` is read correctly by *pytest* when I just run `/my_project/ $ pytest` from the command line?

Extra info incase useful:

```
(my-project-env) /Users/me/Documents/my_project/ $ pytest
============================================= test session starts =============================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.0.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/me/Documents/my_project
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but may I suggest that you run `pytest` from inside the folder where you put your `pytest.ini` file?

```
cd tests
pytest
```

I think that may solve your problem.